# git2p4 submit fails because of illegal characters in filenames

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4

Our team uses git2p4 to develop locally on github repo and then submit it to perforce. 
For eg.

*/home/workspace/src/*  - the git repo code (changes present)

*/home/workspace_p4git/src* - the local client workspace associated to a depot on perforce.

When we copy the git repo source code in the perforce local directory, changes are seen in git as unstaged.

**Now my problem:**

There is a file named: abc %28def%29.extension in the git repo.

When I 'git add -A'; it shows me-
**renamed:   abc %2528def%2529.extension -> abc %28def%29.extension**

Maybe this is because Perforce does not allow '%' character in the filename.

Then I try to submit my code to the git repo -  **git p4 submit -M**

This fails with the following error:

*Target file has illegal escape sequence [%xx].*

*command failed: p4 integrate -Dt "abc %2528def62%2529.extension" "abc %28def%29.extension"*

Does anyone has any suggestion to resolve this other than change the filename in git repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Maybe this is because Perforce does not allow '%' character in the filename.

No, it is because [`%25` is the percent encoding for `%`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_the_percent_character).

You need to try and `git mv` back the added file, using \% or %% to see if you can restore the proper % in its name.
Make sure to update first to the latest git version.